# C++ pointers and the identity of pointer in terms of memory allocation

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory, memory-management

As a newbie to professional concepts of programming, I'm thinking of C++ pointer that they are the address of a memory block. And logically anything pointing to them then indeed is pointing to the first variable.

If `int x = 0;` then if `int y points to int x`; Now again if `int c points to int y`, it indeed points to `int x`; I think this is true?

My question is that, regarding the `int y` and `int c`, as two variables which are pointers, how their own memory is managed in C++?

In general, my question is that how memory-allocation is handled for pointers themselves? Since pointers themselves are a prominent way of organizing memory.

Thanks in advance

Comment: An `int` holds an integer value within a certain range. It doesn't point to anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean

```
int x = 0;
int* y = &x;
int* c = y;
```

Then yes, both `y` and `c` point to where `x` is located in memory.

Also, both `y` and `c` are different variables, with their own memory allocated for them. This can easily be verified by printing the address of the variables, i.e. printing `&y` and `&c`.

---

More graphically, it is like this:

```
int x = 0;
```

allocates some memory and initializes it to zero:

```
+---+
| x |
+---+
```

Then

```
int* y = &x;
```

will look like this:

```
+---+     +---+
| y | --> | x |
+---+     +---+
```

And finally

```
int* c = y;
```

will make it all look like this:

```
+---+
| y | --\
+---+    \     +---+
          >--> | x |
+---+    /     +---+
| c | --/
+---+
```

---

Also note that pointer variables are really no different from any other integral variables, the value is just the address of where they point. It's just that the compiler treats them in a special way.

Comment: I think the OP has a second question, though this correctly answers their first. The second is, are the objects `y` and `c` different objects in memory (the pointers themselves).

Comment: No I didn't mean that. I mean y and c are holding an address. How their own memory is calculated. Since they should exist in the process for the process to understand that it holds an address.

Comment: Umm... while "integral" does indeed technically mean "relating to the set of integers", I still think it's better to stick to the ungrammatical but clear use of "integer" as adjective.

Comment: @JanDvorak That's fair, but then this standard function has it wrong. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral

Comment: @JanDvorak Oh but this exists too http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_integer. hmmmm

Answer (score 3):

Pointers are just like other variable and so they are allocated just like other variables. (May be allocated on stack if auto variable, or to heap if allocated dynamically or to data section if pointers are static/global)

For ex:

```
int x = 0;
int *y = &x;
int *z = y;
```

Here y and z are allocated on stack and they both contain the address of x.

y and z are two different objects pointing to the same location `x`.

As an analogy you can see the example below

```
int a = 42;
int b = 42;
```

Here `a` and `b` are two different variables containing the same value.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted this answer. It means they are just regular variable? Good.

Comment: Yes they indeed are. You may later choose `z` to point to a different memory location while `y` may keep pointing to old location and `y` and `z` won't point to same location any more.

Answer (score 1):

> If `int x = 0;` then if `int y points to int x`; Now again if `int c points to int y`, it indeed points to `int x`; I think this is true?

No. If you mean

```
int x = 0;
int *y = &x;
int **c = &y;
```

then `y` and `*c` points to `x` while `c` points to `y`.

> my question is that how memory-allocation is handled for pointers themselves?

Pointers itself are allocated on stack but the objects that they points to may allocated on heap as in case of

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int*10));
```

Comment: @KerrekSB; Could you elaborate it more ?

Comment: All those variables could very well have static storage.

Comment: @KerrekSB; Yes. And I said memory for pointers are on stack. What's wrong?